# What kind of different results or what is the difference between two URL based WMS requests

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wms, leaflet, getfeatureinfo

I am trying to retrieve some WMS layers from geoserver so that I can display them in leaflet and I need to populate a URL field and I noticed that many of the layers that I opened up in openlayers had "GetMap&layers" vs examples that were successful with "GetFeatureInfo&Layers" when being served via URL.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

GetMap-Retrieves a map image for a specified area and content

GetFeatureInfo (optional)-Retrieves the underlying data, including geometry and attribute values, for a pixel location on a map